# Set ReadOnly ACL recursively

Tags: powershell

I want to set Readonly access type recursively on a folder and it's subfolders using the script below :

Any help please?

```
$list = import-csv "C:\Users\username\Desktop\Grouptest.txt"

foreach($sg in $list) {

$grp = $sg.Group

$colRights = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]"ReadANDExecute"

$InheritanceFlag = [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]:: ContainerInherit
$PropagationFlag = [System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]:: None

$objType =[System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow

$objUser = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($grp)

$objACE = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule `
    ($objUser, $colRights, $InheritanceFlag, $PropagationFlag, $objType)

$objACL = Get-ACL "C:\Users\username\Desktop\Test"
$objACL.SetAccessRule($objACE)
Set-ACL "C:\Users\username\Desktop\Test" $objACL 
}
```

The script is working, but if an ACL is set on a subfolder, the script doesn't change the access type but instead duplicate a new on in the parent folder "C:\Users\username\Desktop\Test" with ReadOnly access type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The script below worked, but excluded the parent folder "C:\Users\username\Desktop\Test"

```
    $list = import-csv "C:\Users\username\Desktop\Grouptest.txt"

    foreach($sg in $list) {

    $grp = $sg.Group

    $colRights = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]"ReadANDExecute"

    $InheritanceFlag = [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]:: 
     ContainerInherit
    $PropagationFlag = [System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]:: None

    $objType =[System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow

    $objUser = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($grp)

    $objACE = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule `
   ($objUser, $colRights, $InheritanceFlag, $PropagationFlag, $objType)

    $folder = Get-ChildItem  -path "C:\Users\username\Desktop\Test" -Recurse
      ForEach ($fl in $folder) 
          {

            echo $fl
            $objACL = Get-ACL $fl.PSPath
            $objACL.SetAccessRule($objACE)
            Set-ACL $fl.PSPath  $objACL 
          }

                               }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the `ObjectInherit` inheritanceFlag.
Also, in PowerShell, there is a more consise method for creating an access rule:

```
$folder = "C:\Users\s849668adm\Desktop\Test"
Import-Csv "C:\Users\s849668adm\Desktop\Grouptest.txt" | ForEach-Object {
    $grp = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($_.Group)
    # create the new access rule
    $ace = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($grp, "ReadAndExecute", "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")
    $acl = Get-ACL $folder
    $acl.SetAccessRule($ace)
    $acl | Set-ACL $folder
}
```

Hope that helps